# Adicionar linha RichText Delphi

Tags: delphi, memo

Boa tarde
Tenho um aplicativo que o texto tem que ter Negrito, italico e sublinhado por isso estou usando um TRichText. Até aqui tudo bem
Para o mesmo funcionar na impressão eu fiz RTRLrichText que recebe os valores do TRichText.

Porém... se eu inserir linhas em brancos para que o texto aparece do meio ou para o fim da pagina na visualização e na impressão não sai como na tela. Ou seja não consigo add linhas.

Alguém sabe como ?

Comment: Tem como mostra o seu Código?

Answer (score 0):

Experimente assim:

```
Richedit1.SelAttributes.Color:=clBLue; // Cor Azul
Richedit1.SelAttributes.Style:=[fsBold,fsUnderline]; // Negrito e sublinhado
Richedit1.Lines.Add('Linha'); // Adiciona linha
Richedit1.SelAttributes.Style:=[]; // Volta ao estilo normal
Richedit1.SelAttributes.Color:=clBlack; // Volta à cor normal
```

Achei isso em um [site](http://www.planetadelphi.com.br/dica/4583/-como-adicionar-uma-linha-formatada-(cor,-negrito,-etc)-num-richedit)

Comment: Fiz os testes aqui só não imprimir porque to sem impressora. Visualmente ele adiciona as linhas...